# PHP Instantiate obj class with variable not working

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I found a problem that I not sure if is a bug of the php or on my code (probably mine) so let me show you what is happening:

```
<?php namespace MyApp\Conciliation;

use SimpleExcel\SimpleExcel;
use ForceUTF8\Encoding;
use MyApp\Conciliation\Gol;

class Conciliation {

    protected function equalizeFile($file, $providerName)
    {
        $type = false;
        $nfile = 'public'.$file;

        // TEST 1: the ideal aproach. not working (see error#1 bellow)
        $provider = new $providerName();

        // TEST 2: working, getting the correct response
        $provider = new Gol();

        // TEST 3: working, getting the correct response
        $provider = new MyApp\Conciliation\Gol();

        $provider->equalize($nfile);

    }
```

Note, the `$providerName = 'Gol';`

> **error1**
>   *Class 'Gol' not found*

http://inft.ly/N8Q6F4B

So, there is any way that I could keeping using variables to instantiate aliases similar as above?

---

**Edit, Problem solved: working example**

```
<?php namespace MyApp\Conciliation;

use SimpleExcel\SimpleExcel;
use ForceUTF8\Encoding;

class Conciliation {

    protected function equalizeFile($file, $providerName)
    {
        $type = false;
        $nfile = 'public'.$file;

        $providerName = "MyApp\\Conciliation\\".$providerName;
        $provider = new $providerName();

        $provider->equalize($nfile);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php

If you are calling the class dynamically, you have to use the full path to the class.

So, your call to `equalizeFile` should be something like:

```
equalizeFile("myFile", "MyApp\\Conciliation\\Gol");
```

Comment: I get close to this result earlier but had errors before, now with this tip works, thanks!